# add multiple products to stripe checkout nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, stripe-payments

I am creating an e-commerce site, where the customer will be able to add products to their cart. on checkout, I need all the items in the cart to be put into the stripe checkout page -- what I mean by this is, in my code, I need to pass the image, name, and price of all the products in my cart, into the stripe checkout page...

here's my code so far!

```
const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:1208';
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    var user = "select * from " + tableID + "";
    ibmdb.open(db2ConnString, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        conn.query(user, function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            var productName = "";
            var image_url = "";
            var price = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
                productName = rows[i].NAME;
                image_url = rows[i].IMAGE_URL;
                price = rows[i].PRICE;
            }

            conn.close(function() {
                console.log("closed function")
            });
        });
    })

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'cad',
          product_data: {
            name: ProductName,
            images: image_url,
          },
          unit_amount: price,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
  });
  res.json({ id: session.id });
 
});
```

there will be multiple products in the cart, so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your code right

```
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
                productName = rows[i].NAME;
                image_url = rows[i].IMAGE_URL;
                price = rows[i].PRICE;
            }
```

You need to put these values into an array of objects, where each object is formatted like the `price_data` hash that CheckoutSession is expecting.

So after your for-loop, your array e.g. `price_data_array` would look like:

```
[
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'cad',
          product_data: {
            name: ProductName,
            images: image_url,
          },
          unit_amount: price,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'cad',
          product_data: {
            name: ProductName,
            images: image_url,
          },
          unit_amount: price,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
      .....
]
```

Then when you create your CheckoutSession, just pass that array under `line_items: price_data_array`.